# Graph DFS algorithm using python shows list index out of range while accessing a utility list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, data-structures, graph

In the given program I have used a stack to implement DFS, with a utility list as stack.
This is an iterative approach. 
The error is here as follows:

---> 19             if visited[i] == False:

IndexError: list index out of range

```
    from collections import defaultdict

    class Graph:
        def __init__(self):
            self.graph = defaultdict(list)

        def addEdge(self, u, v):
            self.graph[u].append(v)

        def dfs_stack(self, start, visited):
            stack = []
            stack.append(start)

            while(len(stack) != 0):
               #pop
               i = stack.pop()

               #if not visited: visit and print
               if visited[i] == False: THE ERROR IS ON THIS LINE
                 visited[i]=True
                 print(i , end = " ")

               #push all unvisited adjacent vertices
               for adj in self.graph[i]:
                  if visited[i] == False:
                    stack.append(i)


       def DFS(self, start):
          visited = [False]*(len(self.graph)+1)
          self.dfs_stack(start,visited)



g = Graph()
g.addEdge(1, 2) 
g.addEdge(2, 3) 
g.addEdge(3, 4) 
g.addEdge(4, 5) 
g.addEdge(5, 1) 
g.addEdge(2, 6)
g.addEdge(3, 6)
g.addEdge(8, 7)
g.DFS(8)
```

Comment: Always share the entire error message. Be careful, using `== False` is both unidiomatic and illogical. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of your graph is actually only `6` as your graph is :

```
{1: [2], 2: [3, 6], 3: [4, 6], 4: [5], 5: [1], 8: [7]}
```

you created `visited[]` to be of length `6` and when you access `visited[8]` it will throw `IndexError: list index out of range`.

You need to create `visited[]` be of length equal to `lastvertex` i.e. `8`